# Save array result from a for loop to a variable

Tags: java, arrays, average

I have an assignment where I am supposed to have 6 elements in an integer array and program supposed to find the highest and lowest element in an array and omit those two elements and find the average for the remaining four elements. So far my program is able to find the lowest and highest number in that array and able to omit it, however, I cant seem to save those results from the loop to a variable so I can start to calculate my average. the code is

```
int bucky[] = { 4, 6, 8, 19, 199, 400 };
int hello = 0;
int max = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < bucky.length; i++) {
    if (bucky[i] > max) {
        max = bucky[i];
    }
}
System.out.println("Max number is " + max);

int min = 0;
int j = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < bucky.length; i++) {
    if (bucky[i] < bucky[j]) {
        min = bucky[i];
        j = i;
    }
}
System.out.println("min number is " + min);

System.out.print("{");
for (int i = 0; i < bucky.length; i++) {
    if (bucky[i] != max) {
        if (bucky[i] != min) {
            System.out.print(" " + bucky[i]);
        }
    }
}
System.out.print("}");
```

So far it prints out `{6 8 19 199}`. I want to be able to save them in a variable and calculate the average. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't you sum the array (as you look for the min/max), subtract the min/max from the sum and then calculate the average from there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple program that might achieve what you are after.

What should happen if all elements have the same value?

```
int[] input = {0,1,2,3,4,5};

int max = input[0];
int min = input[0];
int sum = 0;

for(int i : input){
    sum += i;
    if(i < min){
        min = i;
    }else if(i > max){
        max = i;
    }
}

System.out.println("sum for input is : " + sum);
System.out.println("highest value element is : " + max);
System.out.println("lowest value element is : " + min);
System.out.println("sum excluding extreme elements is : " + (sum - min -max));

// have cast the result as a float as i dont know if average should be truncated or not
System.out.println("average excluding extreme elements is : " + ((float)(sum - min -max)/(input.length-2)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String args []){
    int bucky [] = new int [] {4, 6, 8, 19, 199, 400};
    int max = bucky[0];
    int min = bucky[0];
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<bucky.length; i++){

        if(min > bucky[i]){
            min = bucky[i];
        }
        else if(max < bucky[i]){
            max = bucky[i];
        }
        sum += bucky[i];
    }
    sum -= (min + max);
    System.out.println("Max is " + max);
    System.out.println("Min is " + min);
    System.out.println("Sum is " + sum);
    System.out.println("Average is " + sum/(bucky.length-2));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Small program can be developed using arrays in Java as follows, which initially stores very first element of the array in `min`, `max`, and `sum`, then start traversing the array from first element and determine `min` and `max` value elements by comparing them with the current element pointed by `input[i]` of the array. Also add `input[i]` every time to the `sum` variable to get sum of all elements. After having computed `min`, `max`, and `sum` value elements; compute `avg` by subtracting `min` and `max` from `sum` and divide the resultant value by `length - 2`.

```
class ComputeAvg
{
  public static void main (String[] a)
  {
    int[] input = {10,11,12,13,14,15};
    int min, max, sum, avg;
    min = max = sum = input[0];
    int length = input.length;
    for (int i = 1; i < length; i++)
    {
      if (min > input[i])
        min = input[i];
      else if (max < input[i])
        max =  input[i];
      sum += input[i];
    }
    avg = (sum - min - max)/(length - 2);

    System.out.println("sum for input is : " + sum);
    System.out.println("highest value element is : " + max);
    System.out.println("lowest value element is : " + min);
    System.out.println("sum excluding min and max value elements is : " + (sum - min - max));
    System.out.println("Average after excluding min and max value elements is : " + avg);
  }
}
OUTPUT
======
sum for input is : 75
highest value element is : 15
lowest value element is : 10
sum excluding min and max value elements is : 50
Average after excluding min and max value elements is : 12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int sum=0;
 for (int i=0 ;i< arr.length;i++) {
   if(arr[i]!=max && arr[i]!=min) {
     sum=sum+arr[i];
  } 
}

int average=sum/(arr.length-2)
```

Comment: The problem is that if you have two times the min or two times the max in the array (like {1, 1, 4, 6, 7, 9, 9}), you will remove them both (but still divide by lenght-2). And your code doesn't address the problem of finding the min/max.

Answer (score 0):

You're 90% there.  You just need a nudge in the right direction.

You already know how to filter your results from highest and lowest with this statement (rewritten to compress nested `if`s):

```
for(int i=0;i<bucky.length; i++){
    if(bucky[i] != max && bucky[i] !=min) {
       // implementation
    }
}
```

By the way, it can be rewritten as this, thanks to [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).  This may read more straightforward for you:  "If the value in `bucky[i]` is neither max nor min..."

```
for(int i=0;i<bucky.length; i++){
    if(!(bucky[i] == max || bucky[i] ==min)) {
       // implementation
    }
}
```

**That was the hard part.**  What you now need:

- A counter to tell you how many values you actually *are* adding.  Something like `adjustedTotal`.  You'd only ever add to this counter if the number wasn't the min or the max.
- A simple `sum` variable, initialized appropriately, taking the values from `bucky[i]` such that `bucky[i] != max && bucky[i] != min`.

Comment: The problem is that if you have two times the min or two times the max in the array (like {1, 1, 4, 6, 7, 9, 9}, you will remove them both.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an variable named **sum** like **Makoto** mentioned above.

In additional, I would like to point out that there is something wrong with your code for calculating **min**.

Here is an example,

Assume the int[] array is as follows:

```
int bucky[] = { 6, 4, 8, 19, 400,199 };
```

Use your code below:

```
    int min = 0;
    int j = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < bucky.length; i++) {
        if (bucky[i] < bucky[j]) {
            min = bucky[i];
            j = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("min number is " + min);
```

What will be the value for **min** ?

It will be **0**. It is incorrect.

`You can first specify the first element in array as min, and then compare it with remaining values. If any value is smaller than min, then change the value for min.`

Here is an example:

```
int min = bucky[0];
    //int j = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < bucky.length; i++) {
        if (bucky[i] < min) {
            min = bucky[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("min number is " + min);
```

Make some change and move on. :)